# helm install: Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Going thru https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/

```
ls -R mychart/ mychart/: charts  Chart.yaml  templates  values.yaml

mychart/charts:

mychart/templates: configmap.yaml
```

trying to install the chart:

```
helm install full-coral ./mychart
```

but it fails with:

```
Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name
```

Helm:

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.1", GitCommit:"5270352a09c7e8b6e8c9593002a73535276507c0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.1", GitCommit:"5270352a09c7e8b6e8c9593002a73535276507c0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Not a fix for you but I would STRONGLY suggest that you upgrade to using helm version 3. It removes the need for tiller and therefore is less moving parts to break. Your syntax is right according to v3 syntax btw. Maybe there is a version mismatch between the version of helm you are running and the documentation you are looking at.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your `install` command the name is specified as for Helm v3.

In Helm v2.14 the chart name is specified via `--name`.

> -n, --name string              release name. If unspecified, it will autogenerate one for you

See: https://v2-14-0.helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-install

So in your case this should work

```
helm install --name full-coral ./mychart
```